# Controlled component with react-form library, pre-filled inputs

Tags: reactjs, forms, redux

I'm using [react-form](https://react-form.js.org) to build up forms in a web based application. I'm using Redux too.

I'm in the situation where I need to use these forms to edit information rather than just enter information. This leads me to think I need to make sure that the forms, or the inputs, becomes controlled components that renders values from the Redux store - or any state data really.

How can I achieve that? I can not find this in their documentation etc.

**EDIT**

The library `react-form` is now discontinued, in favour of other libraries like `informed` or `react-final-form`.

Comment: you want to have default values in you form ? After that all values will come from redux as props.

Comment: I want the default/initial values in the react-form to come from redux props. As if I need to edit a blog post, it would have to render the data of that post in my form first.

Comment: Share your reducer code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that `react-form` doesn't mention this in their documentation is because there's no implementation that refers to controlled components that is particular to `react-form` - meaning that you would create controlled form components in `react-form` the same way you would with a regular React component, by passing a `value` to the input/select/etc components, make sure to manage that value through state updates/actions.

As mentioned in the question though, the library is no longer maintained.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have a good sense for your project and this use case, but in the past I've initialized the local state of the form to the previously saved values in your Redux store. In our system, any changes made in the local state were temporary (lost if they left the page or canceled). It isn't until the user clicks save that Redux gets updated along with our database.

Comment: Yes, this is how react-form works - it uses it's own local state and in my implementation, that's saved to redux store onSubmit of the form. However, the question is how we can pre-fill the form with data from the redux store to edit that data.